# How to set background color IONIC 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I having problems trying to change the background color in just one IONIC 4 (--type=angular) page. I am trying to add a class for the ion-content. In my html file I Have:

```
<ion-content class="fondologin">
...
</ion-content>
```

In my sass I have:

```
.fondologin{
    background-color: #111D12!important;
}
```

The background color is never changed. If I add --ion-background-color:#111D12; in variables.scss the background is successfully changed for every page but I just one to change the color in one page. How can I achieve this?

Comment: could you try using [ngClass] or [class] attribute and try?

Comment: Are u using this inside app scss file?

Comment: have you tried this `ion-content{ --ion-background: #111D12 !important}`

Comment: I am trying it inside app scss or  inside my component sass with no success

Answer (score 123, accepted):

For some reason I solved it this way:

First of all I added `--ion-background-color:#ffffff;` in the `variables.scss` file inside theme folder.

In my Page scss I wrote:

```
ion-content{

    --ion-background-color:#111D12;
}
```

After that the background was successful set.

Comment: You don't need to add it to variables.scss any more.

Comment: Sorry, but how can I do it on a specific page only? newbie here. If I do that it will affect all the pages.

Answer (score 24):

I am going to repost the top commented answer , with an extra explanation

```
ion-content{
    --ion-background-color:#111D12;
}
```

Starting from ionic 4, Ionic component implements the concept of shadowDOM, and the old method of finding css selectors in the component that implements shadowDOM no longer works

As such, any modification can only be made if you change the variable that the component references

for example, if ion content references

```
--ion-background-color: #ffffff
```

The only way you can modify the background color is by doing this in your css file

```
ion-content{
    --ion-background-color:#111D12;
}
```

Comment: For more information, you can refer this youtube video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_D1lCoYzivA

Answer (score 15):

As of March 2020, using Ionic 5, the following is the only solution that seems to work without interfering with the background color of other elements. Place the following code in variables.scss file:

**WORKING SOLUTION:**

```
ion-content {
  --background: var(--ion-color-primary); // Replace this with color of your choice
}
```

***The following solutions don't seem to work properly in Ionic 5.***

**Example 1:**

```
ion-content {
  --ion-background-color: var(--ion-color-primary);
}
```

**ISSUE FACED:** Using the above code also changes the background color of List Items, Ionic Cards, etc. to primary color. So this makes them look ugly!

**Example 2:**

```
ion-content {
  background-color: var(--ion-color-primary);
}
```

**ISSUE FACED:** Using the above doesn't apply the background color at all!

**Example 3:**

```
ion-content {
  background: var(--ion-color-primary) !important;
}
```

**ISSUE FACED:** Using the above doesn't apply the background color at all!

Answer (score 9):

You can use like this...working good on my page.

```
ion-content{
    --background: #fff url('../../assets/imgs/intro.png') no-repeat center center / cover;
}
```

I hope it helps you :)

Answer (score 6):

In My Variables.scss file I write this code and then it applies in every file.

```
 ion-content{
    --background:#f9f9f9;
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

**Also works in android deploy,**
If you need transparency in your background. 
You must setup like this way, i tried another way but doesn't work, 
only this way works for me.

```
ion-content {
  --background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
ion-content{
background-color:  #000000(use your color here) !important;
}
```

and let me know it is working for you or not

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem on Ionic 5

I use this solution based on other answers

in template:

```
<ion-content class="wrapper">
...
</ion-content>
```

in global.scss:

```
:root {
    --ion-bg-color: #f5f6fa;
}

ion-content.wrapper {
    --background: var(--ion-bg-color) !important;
}
```

or more simple:

```
ion-content {
    --background: #f5f6fa !important;
}
```

I also use this post:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties

Answer (score 0):

It might be you CSS selector that is not enough acurate.

Try this :

```
ion-content.fondologin{
    background-color: #111D12!important;
}
```

If it is still not working, then inspect your ion-content element and try to find your CSS, and which property or other selector is overriding it

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
    :host {
      ion-content {
        ion-background-color: #d5ffd5;
      }
    }

//Or 

 page-name{
      ion-content {
        ion-background-color: #d5ffd5;
      }
    }
```

Comment: It is recommended to add some descriptions for the answer you've posted

Answer (score 0):

For changing the background on only one page:

```
ion-content{
--ion-background-color:  #00ABE1 !important;
}
```

Do not forget the !important or it might not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a different approach.
Rather than dealing with the `ion-content` background directly, just wrap what is inside of the `ion-content` and apply the background to the wrapper itself.
Example:

Component.html

```
<ion-content>
<section class="wrapper">
 ...
 </section>
</ion-content>
```

Component.scss

```
ion-content .wrapper {
min-height: 100%;
background: #EBEBEB;
padding-buttom: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it was overriding `.sc-ion-card-ios-h` to set my cards colors

```
.sc-ion-card-ios-h {
    border-radius: 13px;    
    background-image: url("/assets/img/bg-panel.png");
    background-size: cover;
    border: outset 2px hsl(195deg 46% 40%);
    @media (max-width: 768px) {
      margin-inline-start: 0px;
      margin-inline-end: 0px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<IonContent color="primary" >   </IonContent>
```

you can also use 
"primary", "secondary", "tertiary", "success", "warning", "danger", "light", "medium", and "dark".

For adding additional color , please check https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/colors