# how to set header background color in ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework

I am trying in different way which I followed link([How to set background color IONIC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53531819/how-to-set-background-color-ionic-4)) for header background color and tried as per ionic 2 and ionic 3 as well:

I am able to make background color for ion-content, but background color is not coming for header.

Code:

```html
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar style="background-color: red">
        <ion-title>Login</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

Please need your support.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It seems like the ion-header acts more as a container for an inner ionic component (like an ion-toolbar).  I looked over the Ionic v4 ion-toolbar [documentation](https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/api/toolbar#css-custom-properties). This component has many custom css custom properties, including --background, that can be customized. This may be what you're looking for.

Assuming you used the CLI to create a 'login' page component, you can add a new css class definition to the **login.scss** file:

```
.new-background-color{
    --background: #54d61c;
}
```

And then refer to it in your **login.page.html** file:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar class="new-background-color">
        <ion-title>Login</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

Answer (score 19):

I've used the following code snippet to change color of header:

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar color="primary">
        <ion-title>Login</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

Instead of **primary** color, you can use any custom color from variables.scss file.

Comment: This is the intended Ionic way -- extend the `variables.scss` file in the `theme` folder to add terms other than `primary`.

Answer (score 12):

in your variable.scss

```
--ion-toolbar-background: var(--ion-color-primary)
```

or if you want to set background for single page you can define a css class like this:

```
.my-toolbar{
    --background:  var(--ion-color-primary);
}
```

or

```
.my-toolbar{
    --background:  red;
}
```

or like farhad said

```
<ion-toolbar color="primary">
```

Answer (score 9):

All the answers I have seen so far seem to hinge on changing the value primary colour, affecting all the buttons and other UI elements. All I wanted was for my toolbars to all change to one colour, so this is what I put in variables.css

```
ion-toolbar {
    --color: #ffffff;
    --background: #0d2c6c;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The background of the `ion-toolbar` seems to rely on variable that is set internally by ionic using the `--background` variable. The color of icons is set using the `--color` variable. So to change it, you should do this

```
ion-header {
  ion-toolbar {
    // set background color
    --background: #0d2c6c;
    // set icon/text color
    --color: #ffffff;
  }
}
```

You can also do something like

```
ion-header {
  ion-toolbar {
    // set background color
    --background: linear-gradient(to right, #000852 0%, #013291 50%,  #000852  100%);
    // set icon/text color
    --color: var(--ion-color-secondary);
  }
}
```

Also note that you can edit height, min-height and much more on the `ion-header` element.

Here's a reference [Ionic Docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs)

Answer (score 1):

`ion-header` should be provided the `background-color` like below:

```
ion-header {
  background-color: #397ffc !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the style tag is set on `<ion-toolbar>` that's where the changes are being applied. Add `style` to `<ion-header>`.

Comment: I have tried following code but still not worked:                                                       
 <ion-header style="background-color: red">
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Login</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

Comment: Try this : <ion-header color="red">

Comment: Try color="red" in a ion-toolbar &/or ion-navbar. Ion-Navbar is how I have used it

Comment: While adding ion-navbar, getting error as: 'ion-navbar' is not a known element.  Please check the link: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/angular/BREAKING.md#navbar where it seems navbar has been replaced with ion-toolbar